# Embedding Solvable Groups into M-Groups

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group.

It is well-known that if $G$ is an $M$-group, then $G$ is solvable, due to Taketa. The converse is not necessarily true: $SL(2,3)$ is solvable, but not an $M$-group.However, Dade proved that every solvable group embeds into an $M$-group.

The proof uses induction and the wreath product to show that for any solvable group $G$ there exists an $M$-group $G'$ such that $G$ is a subgroup of $G'$.

I think that results about the structure of $G'$ are probably too difficult, so I am curious about the index of $G$ in $G'$. The use of the wreath product in the existence proof suggests that $G'$ could be very large. Is someone aware of results in this direction? Or perhaps a more constructive proof than Dade's?

Comment: Isn't the proof constructive, in that it gives you an iterated wreath product of prime-power groups?

Comment: Lots of existence proofs use wreath products to find some large containing group, but they are very rarely even the right order of magnitude for a "minimal" embedding.  In this case, S3 gets embedded in 3 wr 2 of order 18, and S4 gets embedded in (2 wr 2 wr 3 wr 2) of order 4718592.  Even using the wreath product to extend the embedding, one could probably do quite a bit better than this.  Of course if he is just asking for the index from Dade's construction, then yes it is not too hard to bound.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have been more clear. I am looking for 'better' -that is, smaller order- embedding results.

Comment: While it is well-known that an $M$-group is solvable, the definition of $M$-group is not well-known. Somebody care to explain, please?

Comment: The $M$ stands for monomial:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_group
Isaac's Character Theory of Finite Groups is an excellent reference.

Comment: I checked the chapter on M-groups in Between Nilpotent and Solvable.  It is very clearly written and makes Dade's construction seem very natural.  However, it does not have anything beyond Huppert, and so nothing that led me to a systematic decomposition of the general G into wreath products.  Basically you just take the subnormal monomial subgroup which has the most favorable composition series above it, but I don't see any nice way to choose the subgroup or the composition series to get a good and generic bound.